German Children's TV Show with Puppet Spider
I'm trying to recall the name of German TV show that was shown to us in my (USA) High School German class.
I saw it between 2003 and 2005, but the show was likely made in the late 80's or early 90's. We watched the show on a VHS tape, and by 2003 DVD's had become the prominent format.
The show itself was geared for younger children (age 4-7?); the characters would speak slowly and usually repeat phrases multiple times to allow for easier understanding.
The show was called something along the lines of "[Girls Name] and Herr Smit"(man's name might have been different). It revolved around a teenage girl helping out an elderly man, typically by bringing him food, or helping with chores around the house.
One part that stands out to me was the elderly man had a small refrigerator right behind the front door to his house. When the girl came into his house she usually forgot to close the front door. A puppet spider living on-top of the refrigerator and would yell "zu kalt!" (too cold!) until someone came back and closed the door. Then would thank them for closing the door.

This is Anna, Schmidt und Oskar, from the mid 90s.
From the linked Wikipedia-entry:

The show concerns the exploits of Anna, a young music student, who is forced to take care of Mr. Schmidt, a senile old man with magical powers, when her mother, Mr. Schmidt's former caretaker, falls ill.
Oskar is a stray dog who Mr. Schmidt adopts.
  [...]
  Every time someone opens the door to Mr. Schmidt's house, the door spider instructs them to close the door (Tür zu!).

Here is some more information on the episodes in German.

Yep, that's it... And I totally misquoted the door spider.

@onewho Still a great description :)
